# Java Object having properties in debugger but no getter methods

Tags: java, groovy

When I debug through Java code, I often see lot of properties of object that are useful to me in my application to get them and do something with them but I look at the API or javadocs, the class does not have any such properties or getter methods to get these property values. For example:

```
myPhoneCallObj.foo  has value "bar" in debugger
myPhoneCallObj.baz has value otherObj which in turn has other values like otherObj.baz
```

I cannot do in Java:

```
String myValue = myPhoneCallObj.foo
```

as it would not compile in Java but in Groovy I can write above code and during runtime, it gets the value I need. How the same can be done in Java code?

myPhoneCallObj is an instance of Java Interface PhoneCall and the debugger was showing this as of type PhoneCallImpl ( third party implementation of the interface). I do not have access to source code of that third party to look into to understand but the Interface has complete documentation and Javadoc for the APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a class like:

```
class X
{
    private int value;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return (Integer.toString(value));
    }
}
```

You can do this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public class Test 
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv) 
        throws NoSuchFieldException, 
               IllegalArgumentException,
               IllegalAccessException
    {
        final X x;

        x = new X();
        System.out.println(x);
        changeValue(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    private static void changeValue(final X x) 
        throws NoSuchFieldException, 
               IllegalArgumentException,
               IllegalAccessException
    {
        final Class<X> clazz;
        final Field    field;

        clazz = X.class;
        field = clazz.getDeclaredField("value");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(x, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

The key here is the call to `field.setAccessible(true);` which says that even though `value` is private allow it to be accessed.

However there is typically a reason why a field is private, and you should not be surprised if your code breaks with a later release of the 3rd party code that you are manipulating.

Comment: +1 for details. So eclipse debugger is using Java reflection to get all the values of the object even though they are private?

Comment: That one I don't know, there is a debugger API - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/index.html that IDE debuggers probably use.  Likely the debugger API exposes all of that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Are these properties private or protected in scope?  The only properties that you will be able to directly access are public properties, but all variables will show up in a debug object inspector.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to get the value, you can use reflection.  (Which is likely what Groovy is doing)